# How should I practice piano meaningfully at home?

Tags: piano

Every answer I find I don't really know how to put into practice. I don't care about those "HOW TO LEARN PIANO IN FIVE MINUTES", and I can put in time. I just need to know a schedule I can do about every day, and one that I can adapt as I improve. I'm not a complete beginner, and I am familiar with basic music theory, but I'm not good by any means.

Comment: Try a method book?

Comment: What does teacher recommend?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to tell you what schedule will work for you?

Comment: Pick a few tunes you'd like to learn, that match your skill level and learn them from printed out scores, observe the progress and enjoy the process. There's no proper way - it is about what is meaningful for you and what you'd like to do with piano. Most people want to play their favorite tunes and the quickest way to get there is to start learning them. And most enjoyable.